# How do multiple operations function in transformout?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to learn more about Proc Expand and SAS in general.  I haven't been able to shed much light on how multiple operations work together in transformout.  When I run the below code, SAS seems to simply calculate a backward moving sum for two rows.

```
proc expand data=averages out=transformed;
id date;
convert x=y / transformout=(reverse movsum 2 movsum 1 reverse);
by type notsorted;
run;
```

Here is a sample of the results:

```
y        x
13372   1225
20564   12147
16140   8417
14446   7723
13097   6723
15976   6374
11497   9602
12704   1895
18043   10809
```

When I change the code a little bit, I cannot find any patterns with how the numbers are generated in SAS.  Here is the modified code.

```
proc expand data=averages out=transformed;
id date;
convert x=y / transformout=(reverse movsum 5 movsum 3 reverse);
by type notsorted;
run;
```

Here are the results of this code:

```
y        x
116458  1225
112540  12147
106559  8417
103634  7723
107010  6723
103592  6374
103655  9602
100326  1895
94840   10809
```

How does SAS handle multiple operations in this situation?  So far I haven't been able to find anything on google or from trying different scenarios with the code.

Comment: Where is the `TYPE` variable mentioned in the `BY` statement? Or are all of the values you posted for one level of TYPE?

Comment: @Tom Sorry, I should've clarified or removed that piece of code.  The posted values are all of the same TYPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is just calculating the ntermediate result and applying the function to that.  So your use of `movsum 5 movsum 3` is the same as if you did one proc step using `movsum 5` and then did another step using `movsum 3`.

So if you run this program.

```
data have ;
  input x @@ ;
cards;
 1225 12147 8417 7723 6723 6374 9602 1895 10809
;

proc expand data=have out=out1 ;
  convert x=movsum2 / transformout=(reverse movsum 2 reverse);
  convert x=movsum5 / transformout=(reverse movsum 5 reverse);
run;

proc expand data=out1 out=final ;
  convert x=y1 / transformout=(reverse movsum 2 movsum 1 reverse);
  convert movsum2=y2 / transformout=(reverse movsum 1 reverse);
  convert x=z1 / transformout=(reverse movsum 5 movsum 3 reverse);
  convert movsum5=z2 / transformout=(reverse movsum 3 reverse);
run;
```

You will see that Y1=Y2 and Z1=Z2.